# Enable a shortcut to permanently open in safe mode

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, safe-mode

I am running a PowerPoint show at a kiosk. The kiosk shuts down every night and powers up in the morning. I have it autolog and open my PowerPoint show at startup. I would like the PowerPoint show to always start in safe mode, but I am unsure of how to do so. I am sure I change the target, but to what?

File properties and error message:

[image]

I have tried placing /safe outside of the quotation. I do not receive an error, but PP wont open in safe mode.

I have also tried this as the target:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" "c:\temp\test.pptx" /safe
```

As @spikey_richie mentioned, it opens a blank PowerPoint in safe mode AND my program in safe mode...but not in a show version.

Comment: Would this help? [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't help for my specific issue. My PP show is a startup process. I would like it to start in safe mode on its own, permanently.

Comment: In your shortcut that loads PowerPoint on start-up, add `/safe` after `powerppt`

Comment: @spikey_richie SO I am changing the target? Here is what I have: "W:\Promo Screens\TEST.pptm"
I have tried to add /safe to that in different variations and I receive an error.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add what variations you've tried, and what error you get? Those help determine the point of failure. In general please don't answer in comments, update the question. That way the relevant info is available for anyone who wants to pitch in without digging it out from comment threads.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can't. I tried `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" "c:\temp\test.pptx" /safe` but it opens a PowerPoint window in safe-mode, and then a separate window with my `test.pptx` NOT in safe mode.

Comment: @spikey_richie I tried the same thing...

Answer (score 4):

So this worked for me:

Create a batch file and include:
`start powerpnt.exe /safe "c:\Users\user\Desktop\test.pptx"`

This opens the file in safe mode. Then just use the batch file to open the powerpoint

Comment: How do you pass in the name of the file you want to open?

Comment: This is assuming he already has filename included in the shortcut target, you just use the full path of the file.

Comment: The OP must have a shortcut to open the file, as that's what happens on start-up. He wants the file loaded, AND PowerPoint to be in safe mode.

Comment: I *think* if you do `start powerpnt.exe /safe "%1"` you can drag-drop a file on top of the .bat file and it'll open it.

Comment: OP says it's an on-startup action, no user interaction required.

Comment: True, so you couldn't use the "%1", your best bet is to hardcode the path into the batch file and have it run on startup

Comment: That seems more logical.

Comment: Great idea. I have tried this and received an error that says "Sorry, PowerPoint cannot read c:\Users\user\Desktop\test.pptx
I have tried to run the batch file as an admin.
My show is macro-enabled. I have double checked trust settings.
I am on a domain workstation running Windows7 (Long story) I remote in to the workstation.
ALSO, I need this to open as a  PP show...

Comment: Did you change the path to where your file is located?

Comment: @mully Yes sir.

Comment: On the properties of the powerpoint file, at the bottom is there a button that says **unblock**?

Comment: Just to be clear: what are the exact results when you run command  `start powerpnt.exe /safe "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" "c:\temp\test.pptx"`? What error- or other messages you get?

Comment: @mully No, I do not see anything like that. The batch file now opens my file in SafeMode, but I need it to open as a PowerPoint Show. I have the extension in the batch file as PPSM. (Yes, I do have a macro running)

Comment: This opens directly into SlideShow view:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" /S "C:\temp\showme.pptx" 

I can't find a way of getting it to open in Safe mode as well, and in fact, even attempting to start a PPSX with the /SAFE parm starts it in normal/safe view, not show view.  Perhaps the two modes are mutually exclusive.  Why does the show need to start in safe mode, though?